If $g \in \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n = G$ has order $n$ then is it part of a generator set for $G$?
Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n = \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$. Pick some $g = (g_1,g_2) \in G$ such that $|g|=n$. Then does there exist an $h \in G$ s.t. $\langle g,h \rangle = G$? And how would you find such an $h$?
I came across this problem in relation to this question. This problem seems really trivial, but I have been struggling to prove it for some days now.
In the case where $\text{gcd}(g_1,n)=1$ the proof is easy, pick $h=(0,1)$ (similarly for if $\text{gcd}(g_2,n)=1$). I'm struggling with the final case. I've tried picking $h=(g_2,g_1) \vee (1,1)$, and using that to construct $(0,1)$ as a linear combination of the 2 (after which you can easily get the whole of $G$), or trying to prove that $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle = \{(0,0)\}$ (in which case $\langle g \rangle \oplus \langle h \rangle = G$), but I keep getting stumped.
Any suggestions? I'd be happy with a proof of existence of $h$, or a construction of $h$.
I have already looked at this question, but it's not answering the question for me.

$\left\lvert g \right\rvert = n$ implies $\gcd (g_1,g_2,n) = 1$.
Applying Bézout's theorem, we get $a,b,k$ satisfying $a g_1 + b g_2 = k n + 1$. We now let $h = (-b,a)$ and obtain $(1,0) = a (g_1,g_2) - g_2 (-b,a)$ and $(0,1) = b (g_1,g_2) + g_1 (-b,a)$.

Why does ||= imply gcd(1,2,)=1?

@Stent   I think you can show if not then a lower power of $g$ will give the identity.

@Stent If $\gcd(g_1,g_2,n)=d$, then $\frac{n}{d} g = (\frac{ng_1}{d},\frac{ng_2}{d})=(0,0)$.
